# Someone caused me to lose reputation with excessive voting on my questions

Tags: support, reputation, voting

It is 14:24 here. When I was last on Superuser around 10 hours ago, my reputation was 9147 but now it is 8788. The problem is, yesterday some person gave me votes on my questions excessively and when I checked my reputation window, I saw that there are lots of consecutive votes on my questions one coming after another. As far as I remember, the total points were 160 and I thought that the system would automatically take those points back, but now I see that I've lost more than 160 points because of someone I don't know who apparently is voting excessively for probably getting the "Electorate" badge. According to my calculation, I lost 199 reps because of him and I need this to be corrected.

As far as I understand, in this specific case the system is punishing me as it thinks as if I gave myself votes using a sockpuppet account; but I'm the victim here.

Comment: You want me to massively upvote you back to the right rep?

Comment: Thanks Ivo, I had enough ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the automatic reputation recalc happens, it takes away all of the invalid votes from that other user.

Not only that, it will then run through the entire audit and work out your new correct reputation score.

Keep in mind, any questions since deleted between when you last had your recalc and now will not be included.

At the end of last month, many off-topic, subjective/argumentative, migrated out and duplicate questions were cleaned up as part of regular housekeeping. Most of that means deletion, merging in the case of duplicates.

Your new reputation is far lower than you expected now because of deleted questions/answers you've posted to are no longer "there" to account the reputation for.

This is why you've noticed a far larger drop than the flurry of votes being corrected for.

Comment: Thank you for the satisfactory explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not a punishment against you, but just a recalc of your reputation.

Visit https://superuser.com/reputation when logged in to see your full (and *accurate*) rep report (although that won't help *now*, after a recalc).

Some posts to check on the primary meta:

- [What can cause Actual rep to differ from Shown rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49467/what-can-cause-actual-rep-to-differ-from-shown-rep)
- [Why would I lose rep overnight - could it be related to multiple upvotes from a colleague?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56853/why-would-i-lose-rep-overnight-could-it-be-related-to-multiple-upvotes-from-a-c)
- [rep-recalc tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rep-recalc)

---

#### Short Explaination

Over time, your visible rep score begins to differ from what it should be. Some actions don't reverse their rep changes instantly - for example I know when I was a relatively new user I downvoted someone and then they deleted their answer, this was my first down-vote so I was paying it more attention than usual so had noticed the post was gone, but also that I did not get my 1 rep point back - but https://superuser.com/reputation scored me 1 point higher than the site.

**Personal example:** At this moment I seem to have 7rep too much (1271 on site, 1264 on rep sheet). I would *guess* this is from 3 down-votes I've made on things now deleted (I know at least 2 things I've downvoted before were deleted) and an up-vote on something else that has now been deleted. If/when I get a recalc, I will lose those 7 rep.

Comment: FWIW my current rep is 7644, but the rep link above shows I have only 7167

Comment: About ~200 questions that were closed as off-topic or migrated out were deleted at the end of July. These will cause a drop in rep for those involved in answering them. @sat

Comment: I generally don't answer on offtopics, the migrated ones - that would be few, I suppose. Anyways atleast I have an idea as to the reason for the drop